# PyQT labels cut-off

Tags: python, pyqt

I am working on an Sonos Controller using the PyQT lib.

When i change to netxt or prev track, the labels are updated with the artist, title and album info. They are cut-off tho. Anyone experienced this before ? Its not a length issue, as the cutting off seems to change.
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the code I update the labels with:

```
def currentTrackInfo(self):
    currentTrackInfoDict = {}
    currentZone = str(self.cb.currentText())
    deviceDict = self.sonosZonesCoordinatorsIP()
    for key, value in deviceDict.items():
        if value == currentZone:
            device = SoCo(key)
            track = device.get_current_track_info()
            current_title = track['title']
            current_artist = track["artist"]
            current_album = track["album"]

    currentTrackInfoDict.update({"current_title": current_title})
    currentTrackInfoDict.update({"current_artist": current_artist})
    currentTrackInfoDict.update({"current_album": current_album})

    self.artImage()

    return currentTrackInfoDict

def updateTrackInfo(self):
    self.artistlabel.clear
    self.albumlabel.clear
    self.titlelabel.clear
    self.currentTrackInfoDict = self.currentTrackInfo()
    self.artistlabel.setText("{}".format(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_artist"]))
    self.albumlabel.setText("{}".format(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_album"]))
    self.titlelabel.setText("{}".format(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_title"]))
```

Comment: I don't know much about pyqt but I'm guessing that it's going to be much easier to suggest a fix if there is an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At present you only show where you set the text, but it's likely the issue lies where you create or configure that label widget. Perhaps if you are able to create a small program with just that (or those) label(s), which shows the problem, it will be big improvement. Also `self.artistlabel.clear` looks very suspect. Did you mean `self.artistlabel.clear()` or can you just remove it?

Comment: change `some_label.clear` to `some_label.clear()`

Comment: Please put a better picture.

Comment: hi @PaulRooney  & eyllanesc

You are right, about the clear() - it was a bad copy/past.
Ill make sure to give a better overview, once I am back from the office. 

Thx alot !